# META_INF contents different in jar and war?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

I'm trying to use the appassember plugin to create an embedded tomcat using the [heroku howto](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat), with tomcat7 and oracle-java-7.

I've used these instructions a number of times to convert a working war file with no problems.

The current project is a spring-batch-admin console with a single runner underneath. I'm not the code owner, and not-so-familiar with spring-batch, but it seems happy to be dropped into a 'normal' /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps.

When launched with the auto-generated shell scripts (sh ./target/bin/webapp), I get the following error:

```
ERROR - DispatcherServlet          - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:    Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location    [classpath*:/META-INF/servlet/*.xml]
Offending resource: URL    [jar:file:/vagrant/pairbulkdata_app/downloadjob_batch/target/repo/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-resources/1.0.0.M1/spring-batch-admin-resources- 1.0.0.M1.jar!/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml];   nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:   Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location   [../batch/module-context.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/vagrant/pairbulkdata_app/downloadjob_batch/target/repo/org/springframework/batch/pbdDownloadXmlConfig/1.0.0.M1/pbdDownloadXmlConfig-1.0.0.M1.jar!/META-INF/servlet/service-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [jar:file:/vagrant/pairbulkdata_app/downloadjob_batch/target/repo/org/springframework/batch/pbdDownloadXmlConfig/1.0.0.M1/pbdDownloadXmlConfig-1.0.0.M1.jar!/META-INF/servlet/../batch/module-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry META-INF/servlet/../batch/module-context.xml not found in /vagrant/pairbulkdata_app/downloadjob_batch/target/repo/org/springframework/batch/pbdDownloadXmlConfig/1.0.0.M1/pbdDownloadXmlConfig-1.0.0.M1.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
```

Which seems to imply that it isn't finding the servlet-config.xml file.

The interesting thing, when I go peek into the new myApp.jar vs the old myApp.war files, the contents of the META_INF file have been moved around.
The relevent parts  of the original war is:

```
\META-INF\maven
\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\stuff-to-launch-the-servlet
```

In the fat jar, I'm getting:

```
\META-INF
|-----> maven
|-----> stff-to-launch-the-servlet
```

and WEB-INF doesn't seem to be baked in at all.

Since the class it can't find is in the stuff that got moved around, I'm heading down that rabbit hole.

Why does the jar file include the META-INF at a different path? The original configuration is on the filesystem, because this isn't a onejar, and should get picked up from the CLASSPATH, correct?

Comment: Fat-jars contain a custom classloader which understands jars-inside-jars.    This may be incompatible with embedding a web server unless it can be told to understand the fat-jar deployment scheme.

Comment: Ugh. This is an ugle response, failing at formatting. Apologies.  (1) This isn't a fatjar yet, just an embedded server. The dependencies are all on the classpath at this point (2) I've been running spring-mvc restful api traffic using Java-style configs over tomcat in the fatjar, and everything seems happy.    in that configuration, there is usually a very light web.xml and a few jsp files here-and-there, but this one is doing its bean configuration in the context.xml fun.  What I'm trying to drill into is what happens differently to the loading of that webapp dictory from a jar vs war.